# Can I remove Rhythmbox without getting in trouble?

Tags: 12.10

Since Rhythmbox seems to be deeply integrated in Ubuntu, can I just remove it? Or are there any side effects which I should aware of?

PS: Using 12.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed it here on 12.04 & replaced with Banshee for it's Amazon integration. No negative side effects.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was just curious. Because i don't want to break anything.